# Hide and show text boxes, based on previous text boxes being filled

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm **completely** new to JQuery and JavaScript so I apologize in advance for any obvious misconceptions. Currently, I'm looking for a way to have two text boxes shown to the user, and once they are filled out, the remaining however-many text boxes show up below them.

I've looked into dynamic validation a bit, but I couldn't quite figure out how to integrate it.

My environment is Visual Studio 2013, in an MVC project/ASP.NET approach.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technologrich/tT48f/4/) I found that's *somewhat* related to what I'm trying to do.

HTML:

```
<p>Show textboxes
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Show" onClick="getResults()">Do nothing
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Nothing">
</p>Wonderful textboxes:
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #1
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #2
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
```

The code above that I found is, as I said, similar to what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm trying to make it so that the radio buttons are textboxes, and once they are filled (not empty), it reveals the other textboxes (maybe 3 or 4 more) under it, that were previously hidden. What I'm doing is pretty simple and straightforward, but as I said, I'm brand new to this.

Any ideas on a solution? Even resources on the subject would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Great answers, all helpful. Unfortunately I can't vote up any answers because I'm too new.. Thank you all though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `blur` event and check if both textboxes are not empty show other textboxes  else hide them.

You need to so something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
var flag = false;
$(".text input:text").on('blur', function () {

    $(".text input:text").each(function () {

        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }
    })

    if (flag) $(".remaining").show();
    else $(".remaining").hide();


})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/eqPbm/)

Comment: welcome and glad it helped, you can accept the answer when you get answer of it.

Comment: The only thing that is not *quite* right, is that I need both fields to be required in order to show the hidden box. But that's just a simple logic change.

Comment: yes you can modify a little according to your scenario

Comment: This may seem like a simple question, but how would I make it so that more textboxes appear instead of just one?

Comment: Just add more in that div as we are hiding and showing that div

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#textboxIDA,#textboxIDB').on('input', function() {
    if($('#textboxIDA').val().trim != '' && $('#textboxIDB').val().trim != ''){
        $('#DIVWithTextboxes').show();
    }
});
```

In short, this monitors both textboxes for changes.  When done, you can show all remaining text fields.. in this example, I assume that you would have just one DIV, initially hidden.. containing all the remaining elements you want to show to the user.

"textboxIDA" would refer to the ID *at runtime* of your first textbox, IDB would be the other textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track to be using a class on the textboxes to show and hide along with the `show` and `hide` jquery functions.

I would suggest that you attach an event to the `change` event on each textbox that must be filled before the others become visible.  Each time the text changes, a function should run to check if all the requisite textboxes are filled.  If they are, the other textboxes are shown.  Otherwise, they are hidden.

If you want the textboxes to show and hide as the user is typing, you can use the `keypress` event instead of the `change` event.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<p>Show textboxes
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="r1" value="Show" onClick="getResults()">Do nothing
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="r2" value="Nothing">
</p>Wonderful textboxes:
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #1
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #2
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function ShowHideText(){
    if($("#r1").val().length > 0 && $("#r1").val().length > 0){
        $(".text").show();
    }

    if($("#r1").val().length == 0 || $("#r1").val().length == 0){
        $(".text").hide();
    }
}  

$(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").on( "change", ShowHideText);
    $("#r2").on( "change", ShowHideText);
});
```

UPDATED JS PART

Comment: This is close. When I put information in, they appear. But when I take the information back out, the boxes still remain, which should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `keyup` or `keydown` events of the textfiled. Like in your example change the jQuery to the following and it will show and hide upon the user input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".text").hide();
$("#r1").keyup(function () {
    if($(this).val() != '')
        $(".text").show();
    else
        $(".text").hide();
  });

});
```

Make sure to change the radio button to textfileds in your example and try with this code.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.text{display:none;}
```

JavaScript:

```
function getResults(){
   if($('#t1').val().trim() != '' && $('#t2').val().trim() != ''){
      $('.text').show();
   }
   else{
      $('.text').show();
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Show textboxes
    <input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" onkeyup="getResults()">
    <input type="text" name="t2" id="t2" onkeyup="getResults()">
</p>
Wonderful textboxes:
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #1
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #2
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't really get this to work. Also, I'm trying to get rid of the radio buttons completely.

Comment: I have updated the code, there was a type. I have removed the radio button, that was left by mistake.